# Rdd of Rdd SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Can I put a RDD[Double] into a RDD[RDD[Double]]

I would like to have an RDD in which I can have some normal vectors

```
var vector = sc.emptyRDD[RDD[Double]]

val normal = RandomRDDs.normalRDD(sc,50,1)

vector = vector.union(normal)
```

doesn't work

Comment: No, don´t do that. You can use a RDD[Vector[Double]]